# How to prevent c from interpreting \s of sed

Tags: c, sed

I'm using below command to remove commented, empty lines from a file and search for a particular pattern.

```
sed '/#/d' $file | sed '/^[  ]*$/d' | tr -d '\n' | sed -n 's/^.*tags\s*[{]\s*hosttags\s*=\s*\([0-1]\)\s*[}].*/tags {hosttags = \1}/p'
```

Though the above expression works out to me in shell, I have to use it in C. The problem is in this line.

```
sprintf(buf, "sed '/#/d' %s | sed '/^[  ]*$/d' | tr -d '\n' | sed -n 's/^.*tags\s*[{]\s*hosttags\s*=\s*\([0-1]\)\s*[}].*/tags {hosttags = \1}/p'",file);
```

C tries to interpret \s and compiling fails. Replacing \s with  [[:space]] is not working. 
Please let me know how I can get this working in C.

Comment: BTW; your commandline looks highly inefficient. I believe you can get away with just one call to sed.

Comment: Your sed invocation deletes all lines that contain a `#` symbol!  That's very different than "commented empty lines"!

Answer (score 1):

Double up the backslashes, changing `\n` to `\\n`, `\s` to `\\s`, and so on:

```
sprintf(buf, "sed '/#/d' %s | sed '/^[  ]*$/d' | tr -d '\\n' | sed -n 's/^.*tags\\s*[{]\\s*hosttags\\s*=\\s*\\([0-1]\\)\\s*[}].*/tags {hosttags = \\1}/p'",file);
```

When `\\` appears in C string literal, a single backslash is embedded into the string in its place.

Comment: If I use backslash then I'm protecting it from interpretation by C. But shell(rather sed) also doesn't interpret it the right way and the command fails me to get right output

Comment: What I need is a command/special character so that \s is not interpreted in C. But it should be interpreted in sed. FOr eg <special char>\s in sed should be same as just \s.

Comment: @user2161443: This is exactly what this answer provides. I think you may be misdiagnosing your problem.

Comment: When \\ appears in C string literal, a single backslash is embedded into the string in its place.    --> THis is not happening.

Comment: @user2161443: Please show what evidence you have to back up your last statement ("THis is not happening").

Comment: Are you executing this command with `system()`?. Maybe that doesn't accept complex commands with pipes (|)

Comment: Also, maybe the shell is eating the backslashes. Try escaping every backslash with four backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Replace \s with the POSIX character class [[:space:]].